# Selenium select element with multiple attributes when the id is dynamic

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, nunit

I am writing a test that can  login to a site. I am using C#, with Selenium.
1)there are two ID for password?! why would someone code it like this?
2)the  ID contain number which is dynamic and keep changing each time the page is loaded.

the only different is with the name ID  is:

```
    id="txtPassword_155799780_I_CLND" 
    id="txtPassword_155799780_I"
```

I tried everything.

```
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//div[starts-with(@id,'txtPass') and contains(@text(),'I_CLND')]")); 

    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[starts-with(@id,'txtPassword_')]")[2]);





<input class="dxeEditArea_DevEx dxeEditAreaSys dxh0" id="txtPassword_156029875_I_CLND" type="text" tabindex="0" saveddisplay="[object Object]">

<input class="dxeEditArea_DevEx dxeEditAreaSys dxh0" id="txtPassword_156029875_I" name="txtPassword_156029875" onfocus="ASPx.EGotFocus('txtPassword_156029875')" onblur="ASPx.ELostFocus('txtPassword_156029875')" onchange="ASPx.EValueChanged('txtPassword_156029875')" type="password" saveddisplay="[object Object]" savedspellcheck="[object Object]" spellcheck="false" style="display: none;">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kind of all over the place. I would try and use something like the below xpath. I can't tell if you have two "password" elements displaying on the page or just one. Post the html and we can help you better.

```
  //input[contains(@id, 'txtPassword')][1]

  or 

  //input[contains(@id, 'txtPassword') and @type='text']
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the html. Added some options for you.

Comment: Try the above and if it worked accept the answer. If not let us know what happened.